# Why HTTP request POST and PUT in laravel and .htaccess file of public folder, that works great in local machine, not working in live server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I am building a restful api in laravel 4.2. I developed the api in my local machine and it works great. But, when I migrated it to live server, HTTP POST and PUT request returned the following exception:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

This is my route file.

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){
        Route::post('login', ['as' => 'api.v1.users.login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@login']);
        Route::delete('logout', ['as' => 'api.v1.users.logout', 'uses' => 'UsersController@destroy']);
        Route::post('register', ['as' => 'api.v1.users.register', 'uses' => 'UsersController@register']);
        Route::put('change-password', ['as' => 'api.v1.users.change.password', 'uses' => 'UsersController@update']);
        Route::post('forgot-password', ['as' => 'api.v1.users.forgot.password', 'uses' => 'UsersController@forgotPassword']);
        Route::get('recover/{code}', ['as' => 'api.v1.users.recover', 'uses' => 'UsersController@recover']);
    });
```

I ran

```
php artisan routes 

    | POST api/v1/login                | api.v1.users.login             | UsersController@login 
    | DELETE api/v1/logout             | api.v1.users.logout            | UsersController@destroy
    | POST api/v1/register             | api.v1.users.register          | UsersController@register
    | PUT api/v1/change-password       | api.v1.users.change.password   | UsersController@update
    | POST api/v1/forgot-password      | api.v1.users.forgot.password   | UsersController@forgotPassword 
    | GET|HEAD api/v1/recover/{code}   | api.v1.users.recover           | UsersController@recover
```

It shows the uri and it's related controller and methods. I can't figure it out the problem. Do we need to reconfigure laravel for live server? I am using POSTMAN as a rest client.

Also .htaccess file of public folder is not working in live server. I have to write url like

```
http://somedoman.com/index.php/api/v1/login
```

instead of

```
http://somedoman.com/api/v1/login
```

why is .htaccess not working when it's exist in public folder? mod_rewrite is enabled. I also changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.

This is the content of .htaccess of public folder.

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: The contents of your htaccess file would be instrumental in providing any relevant and meaningful help. With what you've given here, the best anyone could do is give you generalized pointers and make wild guesses as to the problem. Please edit some relevant details into your question -- the fully qualified class name of the exception isn't very germane to the problem.

Comment: Give this a read, and try to modify your question to help us help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Chris Sorry for that one. I modified my question. Hope you can assist me.

Comment: Maybe `RewriteRule ^ index.php [P]` instead of `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia Thank you but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: I guess there was some server configuration issue. I have shifted my project to another server and it is working. I still don't know why it didn't worked in AWS server. Anyway, thank you guys for your valuable time and reply.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue and i tried this hack. It worked for me like a charm.
In your filters add this code.

App::before(function($request){

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

if (Request::getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
    $headers = array(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, content-type',);
    return Response::make('', 200, $headers);
}
```

});

Not forgetting i used angular for the  frontend and i added this on every request

app.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider){

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

}]);